# Summing up all rows for each column

Tags: tableau-api

Please find attached workbook in the post.[Post at Tableau community forum](https://community.tableau.com/thread/300052)

This is what I am doing:

I have a list of tasks with a start date and assigned to one of the companies.
I want to find the time it takes between the tasks for every company. Then I need to categorize those hours in one of the 5 categories such as [if hours less than 5 then "On Demand"] and so on. 
I want a view which can show name of the company and count of each of the categories. I am unable to attach the workbook here so if you want refer it then find the link above.

So, steps are:

1) find hours between consecutive dates for each company.

for ex: company 1 start date 1 : null

company 1 start date 2 : datediff('hour',start date, start date 2)

company 1 start date 3 : datediff('hour',start date 2, start date 3)

company 2: start date 1 : null
company 2 start date 2 : datediff('hour',start date, start date 2)

2) categorize hours into different categories.
eg: if hours less than 5 then "On Demand"

Now I want the view as:

company     Category1         category2

CA                   1

MA                    20                        30

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Please consider reading [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and update accordingly. This will help you get better answers more quickly.